# Windows Taskbar/ Jumplist Bug/ Glitch

Tags: windows-8, taskbar, icons, styles, jumplist

I have a problem with my Windows 8.1 Taskbar/Jumplist.
When I right-click any icon in my taskbar the background/ icons are completely bugged (As you can see on the screenshot). It is not resolved even after a reboot.

Has anyone ever faced this kind of bug and know how to fix it?

**Here is a screenshot:**

[image]

(The upper border (Windows 8 Style) is created using a mouse-over.)

Comment: Have you changed the DPI setting through the registry?

Comment: @LPChip Not that I know. But I resetted the DPI regestry-key to default and restartet - Still the same problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you use a 3rd party Windows 8 Theme under Windows 8.1.

I know that the Program [StartIsBack+](http://startisback.com/) fixes this incompatibility.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Windows Update (Update history) and uninstall KB3072318. It has something to do with rolling out Windows 10.
It will work!